# Why does my PHP Calculator doesn't evaluate a error message after typing letters into number fields?

Tags: calculator

I tried to code a simple calculator in PHP, and if I type in numbers everything ist perfect, but if I try to type in letters or words into the number fields, there should be shown a error message, that one of the numbers isn't a numeric sign. But for some reason it is not working. I showed my PHP Code in the follwing picture I will show my html-Code which is named *Taschenrechner.php* and my php-Code which is named *Taschenrechner2.php*.

Thank you very much for your time and help
best wishes

Here is my Code of the PHP-Form1

```
<?php include("kopf.inc.php");?>
```

And here is my PHP Code from the Evaluation of the typed in numbers

```
<?php include("kopf.inc.php");?>
```

Here are two pictures of the failure text
Picture of my PHP-form output

And Picture of the PHP output

Comment: Please edit your question for add the code. Without it it's very difficult to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I Cant see much of your code besides include statements.

of you Declare a variable in php you dont assign the datatype. The Datatype is assigned when you assign a Value to a variable.

```
<?php
    $Variable = 1; //makes $Variable a Integer
        echo $Variable . "\r\n";
        echo gettype ($Variable) . "\r\n";
    $Variable = 'nun ist $Variable ein String'; //changes the datatype from Integer to String.
        echo $Variable . "\r\n";
        echo gettype ($Variable) . "\r\n";

    $StringOne = 'S1';
    $StringTwo = 'S2';

    $ResultTwoStrings = 'ResultTwoStrings';
    $StringOne + $StringTwo = $ResultTwoStrings;
    echo $ResultTwoStrings;
?>
```

This will Result in the fallowing output:

```
1
integer
nun ist $Variable ein String
string

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in ./Playground/file0.php on line 13

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in ./Playground/file0.php on line 13
ResultTwoStrings
```

I am not sure why you dont get an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Good evening everybody, after I lacked a little bit in motivaton during the last few months I noticed, that I forgot posting my code. A little bit embarassing. But now, I had a spelling mistake with my variables so they were not the same but thank you everybody